# How to go through Effect (Array String) in purescript

Tags: purescript

I'm learning purescript and trying to log a directory content.

```
module Main where
import Prelude
import Data.Traversable (traverse)
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Node.FS.Sync (readdir)
fnames = readdir "."
main = do
  travere (\a -> log $ show a) fnames
```

I want to get folder entries printed in console output.
I can not get rid of (or pass through) the `Effect` which I get from `Node.FS.Sync (readdir)` (I get `Effect (Array String)`). And `traverse` or `log` or `show` can not work with `Effect` in front of `Array String`.

I get `No type class instance was found for Data.Traversable.Traversable Effect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Effect` is a program, not a value. `Effect (Array String)` is a program that, when executed, will produce an `Array String`. You cannot get the `Array String` out of that program without executing it.

One way to execute this program is to make it part of a larger program, such as, for example, your `main` program. Like this:

```
main = do
    ns <- fnames
    traverse (\a -> log $ show a) ns
```

Of course, there is really no need to put it in a global variable `fnames` before making it part of the `main` program. You can include `readdir "."` directly:

```
main = do
    ns <- readdir "."
    traverse (\a -> log $ show a) ns
```

Comment: What is another way of unwrapping `Either`? I try to create a function like `findFileWithRe dirPath = find myTestWithRe $ readdir dirPath`(a fail). I guess it's no better than `traverse (\a -> log $ show a) fnames` from the original question. I tryed to use your example and replace `traverse` with `find` (like `find myTestWithRe ns`), but it also fails, even when `ns` is `ns <- readdir "."` a line above. But if I replace `find...` with `log $ maybe "not found" identity $ find myTestWithRe ns` - all works ok! I can't get the difference.

Comment: Here's an advice about asking questions in general: whenever you say that something "fails" or "doesn't work" or "complains" or something similar, it is usually very useful (and in most cases even required) to describe the exact way it "fails" or "doesn't work". For example, is there an error message? What is it? Does the failure happen at compile or run time? And so on. Without this information, it is usually very hard, if not impossible, to diagnose your problem.

Comment: `find_file path = find isCsv $ readdir path` does not compile with message `Could not match type Array String with type String while ... (TypesDoNotUnify)`. And for `find_file path = do` + `ns <- readdir path` + `find isCsv ns` - the same error, but for other types: `Could not match Maybe with Effect`.

Comment: What is the type of `find`'s second argument? What is the type of `readdir path`? Are they the same?

Comment: `find` accepts `Foldable` for the second arg, and `readdir path` after application in a `do` block like `ns <- readdir path` should be `Array String`, which is compatible with `Foldable` if I get it right from the docs. But I dont know how to do `:t` command inside a `do` block to check it.

Comment: The type of `readdir path` does not change "after application in the do block". The type of `readdir path` was, is, and always will be `Effect (Array String)`. But the type of `ns` is indeed `Array String`, which is indeed compatible with `Foldable`.